# Google Chrome Lighthouse/Audit Reduce JavaScript execution time - what is "Other"

Tags: google-chrome, lighthouse

[image: Google Chrome Lighthouse/Audit Reduce JavaScript execution time "other"]
What does this "Other" refer to? Should it say "total"? Is it inline scripts taking this much time?

I'm running in Incognito mode, mobile 4G, with all plugins disabled (none are enabled in incognito mode)

Comment: I removed most inline scripts and removed more js files, the score increased but this "Other" time also increased to 5s then #confused ...

Comment: It doesn't seem like it should be "total" either because summing up the items below it doesn't even come close to this number.. gaah what is this crap taking so much cpu and evaluation time.. #confused

Comment: Have you find anything regarding this?

Comment: @hakkim you can probably see any updates on this in the link I provided in my "answer" below https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/8526

right now no news but perhaps "soonish" I am hoping..

Answer (score 3):

Seems like at the present time Chrome doesn't offer any more information as to what it is...

Please vote on this issue: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/8526